# VBScript LDAP query into Array

Tags: arrays, vbscript, ldap

I am in need of sending a query to LDAP as a Wildcard.  I have the following code:

```
Function SearchLDAP(strUsrName)

Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 

objCommand.CommandText = _
    "SELECT cn FROM 'LDAP://DC=SYSTEL,DC=LOCAL' WHERE " _
    & "objectCategory='user' AND cn = '" &strUsrName&"*'"  
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
objRecordSet.MoveFirst

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    'Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("cn").Value
    Dim strReturnUser : strReturnUser = objRecordSet.Fields("cn").Value
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop

SearchLDAP = strReturnUser

End Function
```

If I run msgbox SearchLDAP("A"), it will display a messagebox with the last entry only.  If I uncomment the line "Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("cn").Value" it will output to console all the entries.

What I need to be able to do is to have all the returned values displayed in a message box like : "User 1; User2; User3;" etc...  Not individual message boxes but all entries in one output.

I need to do this by just running the function like "msgbox SearchLDAP("A"), not having the "msgbox" in the function itself.  Make sense?

I can't seem to figure out if this needs to be in an array and if so, how to get the entries into 1 array that I can then output.

Thanks in advnace!

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it.  Move the strReturnUser variable outside of the Do Loop and just keep building the string.

```
Dim strReturnUser

strReturnUser = ""

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    'Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("cn").Value
    strReturnUser = strReturnUser & objRecordSet.Fields("cn").Value & "; "
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop

SearchLDAP = strReturnUser
```